# Display month and year on chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a line chart created after data that's stored like this:

```
     A       B        C        D
1 | 2017   |        | 2018   |      |
2 | NOV    |        | FEB    |      |
3 | 0      | 0      | 2079   | 2079 |

4 | DEC    |        | MAR    |      |
5 | 0      | 0      | 2800   | 2900 |
6 |        |        | 100    |      |
```

The chart uses values from columns B and D, which can be a =SUM from column A ***or*** C.
The chart has these options:
`Data range: B1-100,D1-100`
`Combine ranges: vertically`
`Plot null values`

It looks like this:
[image]

What I wish to do now is also display the month and year on the chart, so I can identify to what period the points belong to. Something like:
[image]

I cannot figure out how I would configure the chart in order to display these.

Comment: One idea might be to set the main chart transparent, and then create another chart behind it that displays the year and months. Still experimenting how the data should look though, as the number of points needs to be the same on both charts in order to match wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution without doing major changes to my data set, so I've chosen to create another chart based on the following data:

```
Chart axis   years  years Annotations
ian          | 0  |   |       
feb          | 0  |       
mar          | 0  |       
apr          | 0  |       
mai          | 0  |       
iun          | 0  |  2016 
iul          | 0  |         
aug          | 0  |         
sep          | 0  |         
oct          | 0  |         
noi          | 0  |         
dec          | 0  |
```

Years column is set to 0 so the data points are all at the base of the cart.
Then I make the main chart that holds the actual numbers transparent, and move this second chart behind it. It looks like this:
[image]

It doesn't align perfectly with the data points.
Far from ideal, but works.
Based on: https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/data-labels/